# What is .intValue() in Java?

Tags: java

What is the difference between them?

*`l` is an arraylist of Integer type.*

version 1:

```
int[] a = new int[l.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++) {
    a[i] = l.get(i);
}
return a;
```

version 2:

```
int[] a = new int[l.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++) {
    a[i] = l.get(i).intValue();
}
return a;
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

`l.get(i);` will return `Integer` and then calling `intValue();` on it will return the integer as type `int`.

Converting an `int` to `Integer` is called **boxing**.
Converting an `Integer` to `int` is called **unboxing**
And so on for conversion between other primitive types and their corresponding Wrapper classes.

Since java 5, it will automatically do the required conversions for you(autoboxing), so there is **no difference in your examples if you are working with Java 5 or later**. **The only thing you have to look after is** if an `Integer` is null, and you directly assign it to `int` then it will throw NullPointerException.

Prior to java 5, the programmer himself had to do boxing/unboxing.

Comment: Prior to Java 5, the programmer would also need to cast to Integer before calling intValue.

Answer (score 9):

As you noticed, `intValue` is not of much use when you already know you have an `Integer`. However, this method is not declared in `Integer`, but in the general `Number` class. In a situation where all you know is that you have some `Number`, you'll realize the utility of that method.

Answer (score 5):

The Object returned by **l.get(i)** is an instance of the **Integer** class.

**intValue()** is a instance method of the **Integer** class that returns a primitive **int**.

See Java reference doc...
[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#intValue()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#intValue%28%29)

Comment: plus: in version 1 the JVM applies autoboxing to convert the `Integer` instance into a primitive type

Comment: what is the potential dangerous if i'm not calling .intValue() in my case.

Comment: As mentioned by hage, Autoboxing should do the necessary for you not to worry. Read this article about it, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html

Comment: @hage, the auto boxing is done by the compiler and not the JVM.

Answer (score 3):

Java support two types of structures first are primitives, second are Objects.

Method that you are asking, is used to retrieve value from Object to primitive.

All java types that represent number extend class [Number](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html). This methods are in someway deprecated if you use same primitive and object type since [autoboxing] was implemented in Java 1.5.

> int - primitive
>
> Integer - object

Before Java 1.5 we was force to write

`int i = integer.intValue();`

since Java 1.5 we can write

`int i = integer;`

Those methods are also used when we need to change our type from Integer to long

`long l = integer.longValue();`

Answer (score 2):

Consider this example:

```
Integer i = new Integer(10);
Integer j = new Integer(10);
if (!(i == j)) {
    System.out.println("Surprise, doesn't match!");
}
if (i.intValue() == j.intValue()) {
    System.out.println("Cool, matches now!");
}
```

which prints

```
Surprise, doesn't match!
Cool, matches now!
```

That proves that `intValue()` is of great relevance. More so because Java does not allow to store primitive types directly into the containers, and very often we need to compare the values stored in them.  For example:

```
oneStack.peek() == anotherStack.peek()
```

doesn't work the way we *usually* expects it to work, while the below statement does the job, much like a workaround:

```
oneStack.peek().intValue() == anotherStack.peek().intValue()
```

Comment: This answer deserves +1. I was stuck in one of the DSA question, later realize that I wasn't using .intValue().

Answer (score 1):

`get(i)` will return `Integer` object and will get its value when you call `intValue()`.In first case, automatically `auto-unboxing` happens.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a convenience method for getting primitive value from object of `Number`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html

Consider the code:

```
Integer integerValue = Integer.valueOf(123);
float floatValue = integerValue.floatValue();
```

The last line is a convenient method to do:

```
float floatValue = (float)(int)integerValue;
```

Since any numeric type in Java can be explicitly cast to any other primitive numeric type, `Number` class implements all these conversions. As usual, some of them don't make much sense:

```
Integer integerValue = Integer.valueOf(123);
int intValue = integerValue.intValue();
int intValue2 = (int)integerValue;
int intValue3 = integerValue;
```

Comment: You should not use `new Integer(123);` Integer.valueOf(123) is recommended.

Comment: Any objective reason or just "they say so"?

Comment: Java use cache for integers, using new Integer you always create new Object. Using valueOf you can use value from cache. This have good and bad sides but generally it is not required to have two objects representing number one.

Comment: I would not use `Integer.valueOf(123)` either when just `123` will do fine (and the same thing actually).

Answer (score 0):

They are exactly the same. As other posters have mentioned, you can put either the `Integer` object or the `int` primitive into the array. In the first case, the compiler will automatically convert the `Integer` object into a primitive. This is called auto-boxing.

Comment: so, java will convert Integer to int automatically by calling .intValue() in this case? from a reference to value type?