# How to compare two Integers in java

Tags: java, integer

I want to compare elements in two list using < > ==

Is it the right way  to use intValue()?

```
List<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
a.add(129);

List<Integer> b = new ArrayList<Integer>();
b.add(128);

if(a.get(0).intValue() > b.get(o).intValue()) {
   // something
}
```

Comment: Or even better: `a.get(1).compareTo(b.get(1)) == 0`.

Comment: if I also need < > , you mean only change this with <0 and >0 in the right?

Comment: @user3495562 Yes, you got it, this is how `compareTo` works

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11490425/what-is-intvalue-in-java
maybe read that :) And don't use intValue() because you don't need it.

Comment: @user3495562 the compareTo method usually output an int (-1, 0, and 1), you need to modify your if statement accordingly.

Comment: Could YOu explain why java need Integer with int already there?

Comment: int is a primitive type and breaks the OO logic, while Integer is a pure Java class and can be extended and contains more methods

Comment: Integer is a reference type, int is a primitive type.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're making it the right way.

As stated in the comments, you could also you `compareTo()`.
An alternative to `compareTo()` is `equals()` which won't throw a NullPointerException in the case where the object is null.

Answer (score 2):

Your way is correct. But with a small correction.

1)

```
a.get(0).intValue() == b.get(0).intValue()
```

2)

```
a.get(0).equals(b.get(0))
```

This is the problem in your code, you have to **get(0)**, instead of **get(1)**. Remember, in java it **always start with 0**.

Values can be compared using `equals()` or CompareTo method as well.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        List<Integer> a= new ArrayList<Integer>();
        a.add(128);

        List<Integer> b = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        b.add(128);

        if(a.get(0).intValue() == b.get(0).intValue()){
            System.out.println("success");
        }else{
            System.out.println("failure");
        }
        if(a.get(0).equals(b.get(0))){
            System.out.println("success");
        }else{
            System.out.println("failure");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe use the edit feature? Or the comment feature? This doesnt answer the question.

Comment: I have tried that code in my local, it wont work ideally with get(0) , inorder to compare first. Have you tried. @martijnn2008