# Incrementing an Integer variable doesn't affect another referencing the same object

Tags: java

I always understood static variables to share one instance whenever they were referenced. I wanted to put this to the test but the results were different than I had expected.

```
static Integer counter = 0;
static Integer test = counter;

public static void main(String args[]) {
     counter++;
     System.out.println("counter: " + counter);
     System.out.println("test: " + test);
}
```

output:

> counter: 1
>
> test: 0

Since `test` references `counter` I thought that when I increment `counter` then `test` will automatically be incremented as well. However, it seems `test` is referencing `0` from somewhere, question is, where?

Comment: They are both primitives not objects. `test` is originally `0`, if you want to increment test, you need to call `test++`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Since `test` references `counter`

This assumption is false. In Java, you cannot reference variables. What is stored in a variable is a value. That value can either be a primitive type value or a reference type value. In the case of primitives, the value is the value of the primitive. In the case of reference types,

> [The reference values (often just references) are pointers to these
>   objects, and a special null reference, which refers to no object.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.1)

In

```
int a = 0;
int b = a;
```

the variable `a` is evaluated to produce a value, `0`, and that value is stored in `b`.

In

```
Integer a = 0;
Integer b = a;
```

`0` is converted to an `Integer` through `Integer.valueOf(int)` and the value, a reference to an `Integer` object is stored in `a`. Then `a` is evaluated, producing the value of that reference to an `Integer` object, and that value is stored in `b`.

This is the same concept discussed in

- [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top)

Also, the fact that the variables are `static` is irrelevant.

The only way around this is to update `test` manually i.e.

```
counter++; 
test = counter;
```

Comment: Is there a JLS reference that talks about the assignment conversion of boxed types to other boxed types explicitly? I looked around and could not find it.

Comment: @merlin2011 Do you mean [boxing conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7)?

Comment: That only talks about `int` to `Integer` and the section after talks about `Integer` to `int`. Here we are looking at `Integer` to `Integer` direct assignment, which is what I couldn't find a reference about.

Comment: @merlin2011 Yes, [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.1), last point. _the value of the right-hand operand is converted to the type of the left-hand variable, is subjected to value set conversion (§5.1.13) to the appropriate standard value set (not an extended-exponent value set), and the result of the conversion is stored into the variable._

Comment: I looked at 5.1.13 and did not find anything about boxing or unboxing. I'm probably misunderstanding it.

Comment: @merlin2011 No, 5.1.13 is just an additional evaluation. The conversion occurs during _the value of the right-hand operand is converted to the type of the left-hand variable_, which is discussed in [5.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2).

Answer (score 3):

Here is my understanding.

- **Step 1:** When you say `Integer counter = 0;`what you're actually doing is
  `Integer counter = new Integer(0);`
         Here you created an `Integer object` whose value is 0 and `counter`    is reffering to it.
- **Step 2:** `Integer test = counter;`

  Now `test` is also referring to the    same `Integer object` we
  created in step 1.
- **Step 3:** Here comes the tricky part. When you do `counter++;` in your    main method, Java **Auto-boxing** and **Auto-unboxing**
  features are    implementing the below code for you.

  `counter = Integer.valueOf(counter.intValue() + 1);`

As `Integer` class is **immutable** in Java, when the value is incremented from 0 to 1, the `valueOf()` method is creating a new `Integer object` and storing the new value 1 in it instead of changing the old object's value (See below for Java's **valueOf()** method implementation). As you're referring the new object with `counter`, it de-referenced  the old `Integer object` whose value is 0. But the reference variable `test` is still holding the old `Integer object`. This is the reason `test` printing the old value.

**Java's valueOf() method from library class Integer**

```
638     public static Integer More ...valueOf(int i) {
639         assert IntegerCache.high >= 127;
640         if (i >= IntegerCache.low && i <= IntegerCache.high)
641             return IntegerCache.cache[i + (-IntegerCache.low)];
642         return new Integer(i); //See, new object is created here.
643     }
```

**See below for detailed diagrammatic explanation.**

Solid line implies reference variable is still holding the object.

Dotted line implies reference variable is no more holding the object.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`test` doesn't reference `counter`. It has the same **initial** value. `int` is a primitive.

Answer (score 0):

`test` is not a pointer to `counter`: you are setting its value to be equal to counter initially, but any subsequent changes to `counter` will not be reflected in the value of `test`.

If you want to have two references to the same mutable value, you can use something like `AtomicInteger`:

```
static AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);
static AtomicInteger test = counter;
public static void main(String args[]) {
     counter.incrementAndGet();
     System.out.println("counter: " + counter);
     System.out.println("test: " + test);
}
```

Output:

```
counter: 1
test: 1
```

Comment: Because it isn't, by specification.

Answer (score -2):

You need to distinguish between a primitive and a referenced-object. Integer are not primitive 'per-se' but they have special properties due to '[boxing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22648627/how-java-auto-boxing-unboxing-works)'. What you have is a primitive due to [intValue()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11490425/what-is-intvalue-in-java) hence it gets the initial value (it has no more relation to the counter).

Well...for the record 'downgraders': the OP has changed his fields from 'int' to 'Integers' and therefore my initial answer was incorrect.