# Java trunc() method equivalent

Tags: java, math, rounding

The java.lang.Math class has ceil(), floor(), round() methods, but does not have **trunc()** one.

At the same time I see on the practice that the .intValue() method (which does actually (int) cast) does exactly what I expect from trunc() in its standard meaning.

However I cannot find any concrete documentation which confirms that intValue() is a full equivalent of trunc() and this is strange from many points of view, for example:

- The description "Returns the value of this Double as an int (by
  casting to type int)" from
  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html does
  not say anything that it "returns the integer part of the fractional
  number" or like that.
- The article
  [What is .intValue() in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11490425/what-is-intvalue-in-java)
  does not say anything that it behaves like trunc().
- All my searches for "Java trunc method" or like that didn't give
  anything as if I am the only one who searches for trunc() and as if I
  don't know something very common that everyone knows.

Can I get somehow the confirmation that I can safely use intValue() in order to get fractional numbers rounded with "trunc" mode?

Comment: There are pretty exhaustive details in the JLS; what's missing from that description?

Comment: "*does exactly what I expect from trunc() in its standard meaning*" Perhaps it is worth defining what you expect `trunc` to do.

Comment: I think he was referring to precision loss issues, like it happens for floats.

Comment: *The description "Returns the value of this Double as an int (by casting to type int)"* says exactly that it "returns the integer part of the fractional number": that's what "casting a double to int" means

Comment: It is clear from the docs that the method *converts* to type int, but it is not said *in which mode* the rounding happens during conversion. I know at least 4 rounding modes: ceil, floor, round, trunc.
@Michael, I expect that trunc() "returns the integer part of the fractional number"

Comment: The [Java 8 version](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html)  of the doc for `Double.intValue()` references Java Language Specification section 5.1.3 _Narrowing Primitive Conversions_;  that should explain _definitively_ what "casting a `double` to`int`" means.

Comment: @Alexander casting's not rounding

Comment: Thanks @Kevin Anderson. This is exactly what I have searched! https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3:
"the floating-point value is rounded to an integer value V, rounding toward zero using *IEEE 754 round-toward-zero mode*". I think it is the direct answer on my question.

Comment: Yep! And the way I read it, "round toward zero" == truncate

Answer (score 2):

So the question becomes: *Is casting a double to a int equal to truncation*?

The [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3) may have the answer. I'll quote:

> specific conversions on primitive types are called the narrowing
>   primitive conversions:

[...]

> - float to byte, short, char, int, or long
> - double to byte, short, char, int, long, or float
>
> A narrowing primitive conversion may lose information about the
>   overall magnitude of a numeric value and may also lose precision and
>   range.

[...]

> A narrowing conversion of a floating-point number to an integral type
>   T takes two steps:
>
> - In the first step, the floating-point number is converted either to [...] an int, if T is byte, short, char, or int, as follows:
>
>   - If the floating-point number is NaN (§4.2.3), the result of the first step of the conversion is an int or long 0.
>   - Otherwise, if the floating-point number is not an infinity, the floating-point value is rounded to an integer value V, ***rounding toward
>       zero using IEEE 754 round-toward-zero mode*** (§4.2.3). Then there are
>       two cases:
>
>     - If T is long, and this integer value can be represented as a long, then the result of the first step is the long value V.
>     - Otherwise, if this integer value can be represented as an int, then the result of the first step is the int value V.

Which is described in [IEEE 754-1985](https://standards.ieee.org/standard/754-1985.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `floor` and `ceil` to implement `trunc`

```
  public static double trunc(double value) { 
      return value<0 ? Math.ceil(value) : Math.floor(value);
  }
```

With [Google Guava DoubleMath#roundToInt()](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/math/DoubleMath.java) you can convert that result into an `int`:

```
  public static int roundToInt(double x, RoundingMode mode) {
    double z = roundIntermediate(x, mode);
    checkInRangeForRoundingInputs(
       z > MIN_INT_AS_DOUBLE - 1.0 & z < MAX_INT_AS_DOUBLE + 1.0, x, mode);
    return (int) z;
  }

  private static final double MIN_INT_AS_DOUBLE = -0x1p31;
  private static final double MAX_INT_AS_DOUBLE = 0x1p31 - 1.0;
```