# What is the use of intValue() when you can directly assign Integer value to primitive int?

Tags: java

```
Integer a = new Integer(100);
int ax = a;
```

Is the above code same as below? If yes then what is the use of intValue() method since we can directly assign value to primitive int?

```
Integer a = new Integer(100);
int ax = a.intValue();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is .intValue() in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11490425/what-is-intvalue-in-java)

Comment: Well, the reason you can write the former is because of auto-boxing. And auto-boxing calls `intValue` to do the job. Take a look at the code after compilation and you will see that both are equivalent.

Comment: @fuat Yup! Thank You